# Firebase vs Parse (What are actual examples of apps when Firebase is preferable?)

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, nosql, comparison, parse-server

I am trying to understand WHEN Firebase is preferable (in terms of the types of apps you would choose Firebase for instead of Parse Server... not just the keyword characteristics)

I have read atleast two dozen articles on this subject as I am trying to gain a confident / solid understanding of the benefits of when you should choose firebase (perhaps over something like Parse).

*The benefits I see at the top of many lists are "real-time updates" and "scalability" but I don't really understand the context of these terms or there ACTUAL benefit here.*

How is Firebase more scalable than Parse?

**And why are "real-time updates" so attractive to some people?** To me all I notice is that in the Firebase DB Console I can see the information on the screen immediately without hitting refresh when something is written to the DB. That's cool but how is that a main benefit? Doesn't seem all that special to me, but maybe I'm missing something here? This article (https://www.anexinet.com/blog/firebase-real-time-database-benefits-overview/) mentions its beneficial for Chatting services (maybe whatsapp?). What other use-case/apps would be beneficial for real-time updates?

The articles(such as https://medium.com/one-tap-software/firebase-pros-and-cons-ce37c766190a) might say something like

> "JSON removes a lot of the constraints from the RDBMS in favor of
>   scalability and standardized data containment."

To me, learning NoSQL has been a challenge, as I come from a Relational Database background where data redundancy is a no-no. I feel like I have had to do a lot of annoying overhead to get the same querying functionality I could get from a RDBMS like MySQL using Primary and Foreign Keys and two or three tables.

Comment: I would also like to know the answers to these questions? Anybody?

Comment: I would also like to know about aggregation possibilities. How would you aggregate results of your queries like GROUP BY aggregations?